# UpdatePanel with "invalid postback or callback argument" error

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, asp.net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got a .ascx server control in ASP.NET 2.0 that contains several other .ascx server controls.  Everything in the top-level one is wrapped in an UpdatePanel.  It works great until the second time I do something on the page, and then I get this error in an alert dialog:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

This seems like a common error; a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22invalid+postback+or+callback+argument%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=MxZ&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=%22invalid+postback+or+callback+argument%22+updatepanel&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1ec92a21f3882047&biw=1280&bih=874) turns up several results.  They all seem to say that if a postback happens, you have to make sure to call Update on any UpdatePanels that contain controls that were updated.  But when I'm debugging this my whole page is contained inside one UpdatePanel (whose UpdateMode is Always), so that doesn't seem right.  What's going on?

Comment: you have an error on the post back, remove for a little the update panel to locate the error.

Comment: @Aristos: If I remove the update panel, everything is fine.

Comment: Make some tests, see what is break... or you have forget to include inside the update panel some elements... make some post backs... One last think be soure that you are not using custom controls that direct write to the output.